# Batch File Not Executing completely

Tags: batch-file

I have made a simple batch file for backing up my repository changes and rebuildig, but it always stops executing after the backup command is run. Have anyone here ever seen this happen before?

Comment: @bma: In some cases it's not particularly obvious what's a normal executable and what's a batch file. Some programs (ant for example) insist on being called by default through a batch file and if you don't know that this can be quite ... confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, if you run another batch file from your batch, you must use CALL, or your batch will stop executing at that point. (Control is transferred to the second batch file, and never returns.)

Running exe's and the like is ok - they return automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I had just found that out and I was going to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

In your second batch file put GOTO:EOF as the last line instead of EXIT

first file:

```
ECHO. FIRST FILE
CALL file2.bat
ECHO. FIRST FILE AGAIN!
PAUSE
```

file 2:

```
ECHO. SECOND FILE
:: your stuff here
GOTO:EOF
```

Would display (results are indented so that its easier to read:

```
C:\Windows\System32> ECHO. FIRST FILE
      First File
C:\Windows\System32> CALL file2.bat
C:\Windows\System32> ECHO. SECOND FILE
      Second File
C:\Windows\System32> GOTO:EOF
C:\Windows\System32> ECHO. FIRST FILE AGAIN!
      First file again!
C:\Windows\System32> PAUSE
      Press any key to continue...
```